# IndexNotReadyException when building the application

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Writing an android application. It has no errors when I run it on an emulator. But when I tried to build it to an apk file to test on a device, I get the following error.

```
com.intellij.openapi.project.IndexNotReadyException: Please change caller according to com.intellij.openapi.project.IndexNotReadyException documentation
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.handleDumbMode(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:853)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.ensureUpToDate(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:802)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.ensureUpToDate(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:786)
    at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl.processElements(StubIndexImpl.java:250)
    at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl.processElements(StubIndexImpl.java:238).......
```

I seen one similar case raised here which mentions to "Wait till indexing is complete."But I am not sure what I am doing to even interfere with any indexing.

Tried on different computers. Same problem. The only thing I did different before I got this error was to add a dependency at gradle(app) for a RingButton and added that RingButton class to the project to modify it to what I wanted. 
As I said it is working fine in emulator.

Just to test if that is indeed the isse, I deleted the class and removed the dependency but the issue is not resolved.

Comment: Do you mean my build.gradle(Module: app)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Dropbox to constantly backup my project every now and then. So I would click my project and send to Dropbox. I was also instantly clicking run to run the app on my emulator at the same time. During this period, when I mouse over my Dropbox icon, there is an indication that it is "Indexing".

Based on previous answer "Wait till indexing is complete", I can only assume this Dropbox indexing interfered somehow.

Not exactly elegant but I copied each and every file in this project into a New Project and everything is working fine now and able to install the apk file. I didn't change anything so I believe there is some form of corruption in the old project.

Answer (score 4):

I think this can be solved by creating a new project and moving the files into the new one.  Maybe the index is corrupt. But before that can you clear the cache ? in android studio if your prepared to lose some local history then try this:

[image]

and then chose invalidate and restart:

[image]

Comment: I just did the invalidate cache. That error no longer shows. But the apk file is still not installable. Build comes out as successful.

Comment: the apk is not installable ? Assuming your trying to install it on a device you have to make sure the device can support this apk. What version of android is the device on and what version of android are you building against ?

Comment: I been using the same project and installed it multiple times before on the same device.

Comment: Now that you mentioned it.. think I did a software update on the device yesterday.. The app I am using API21. The phone is definitely higher that API21 which I believe should not be an issue. How do I check this.

Comment: whats the command your using to install the apk ? your using adb right ? how tell me the method your using once you acquire the apk that you use to install it on the device. I would use adb install -r pathtoAPK/myApp.apk

Comment: I send the apk file to dropbox from my PC. Access dropbox from my phone and open the apk file and install via an apk installer.

Comment: what error does the apk installer produce ? Also, ensure the other apk (the debug one is removed before installing the release one)

Comment: Just says "Unable to install". The IndexNotReadyException is back again and I didn't make any new changes. Invalidad cache and its gone..